# set height of imageview as matchparent programmatically

Tags: android, height, imageview

I need to set the height of an **imageview** as **matchparent** programatically.if it is a fixed height i know how to set.

but how can i set it as matchparent?

**EDIT:**

actually height of the parent layout is dynamic.so i need to make the height of the imageview as the height of parent.

Comment: i have tried all the methods mentioned in the answers.but it is not setting the height as match parent :(

Comment: You should review your accepted answer

Answer (score -19, accepted):

initiate LayoutParams .

assign  the parent's width and height and pass it to setLayoutParams method of the imageview

Comment: you should never pass the parents actual dimensions. Always use MATCH_PARENT instead of actual values. In general I wouldn't recommend using absolute sizes because it might look completely different on all the screens there are. I'd prefer using weights.

Comment: To be honest this should be a comment

Answer (score 291):

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: The moment i press Alt+Enter in LayoutParams, i see so many classes. Can you please tell me which one to use?

Comment: what is the parent view?

Comment: You should use class of view that You want to set LayoutParams i.e. use LinearLayout.LayoutParams to set prams to Your LL :)

Comment: What if you want the height to be dynamic based on the dimensions of the original image but want the width to be MATCH_PARENT?

Comment: import android.view.ViewGroup

Answer (score 67):

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: If you're setting the params for the first time because you made the imageview programmatically, this will null pointer error (or does with text view) and should everywhere else.

Answer (score 17):

For Kotlin Users

```
val params = mImageView?.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
params.height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
mImageView?.layoutParams = params
```

Here I used `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` since my views( `ImageView`) parent is `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 15):

```
imageView.setLayoutParams
    (new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        (width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

The Type of layout params depends on the parent view group. If you put the wrong one it will cause exception.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue. Resolved by firstly setting :

```
imageView.setMinHeight(0);
imageView.setMinimumHeight(0);
```

And then :

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

setMinHeight is defined by ImageView, while setMinimumHeight is defined by View. According to the docs, the greater of the two values is used, so both must be set.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this incase you would like to match parent. The dimensions arrangement is width and height inorder

```
web = new WebView(this);
        web.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MATCH_PARENT constant or its numeric value -1.

Comment: MATCH_PARENT is not defined in the context. You must say 'LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT'