# set view height as matchparent programmatically in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, view, height, android-constraintlayout

I need to set programatically the height of a button as matchparent  in my constraintLayout class.

```
open class Myword @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
     ) : ConstraintLayout(context,attrs) {

    var set = ConstraintSet()
    val tastoetim= Button(this.context)
    init{
        this.addView(tastoetim)
        tastoetim.requestLayout()


        set.connect(tastoetim.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT,this.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 10)
        set.connect(tastoetim.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,this.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)

        tastoetim.minHeight = 0
        tastoetim.getLayoutParams().height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

    } }
```

this does not work.

As already pointed out by author of this post ([set height of imageview as matchparent programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310550/set-height-of-imageview-as-matchparent-programmatically)), none of these answers works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by firstly setting :

```
tastoetim.setMinHeight(0);
tastoetim.setMinimumHeight(0);
```

And then :

```
tastoetim.getLayoutParams().height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

setMinHeight is defined by ButtonView, while setMinimumHeight is defined by View. According to the docs, the greater of the two values is used, so both must be set.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints) for *ConstraintLayout*:

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

In my experience, using *MATCH_PARENT* can have some odd results.

In your case, you will want to do something like the following:

```
open class Myword @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {


    init {
        val tastoetim = Button(this.context)
        // The new Button needs an id, otherwise, it is "NO_ID" (-1)
        tastoetim.id = View.generateViewId()
        val lp = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT
        )
        this.addView(tastoetim, lp)

        // Get the ConstraintSet only after the view is added.
        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(this)

        set.connect(
            tastoetim.id,
            ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            10
        )

        // For match constraints, we need a top and a bottom view to connect to. Here the
        // parent top is assumed, but it could be another view.
        set.connect(
            tastoetim.id,
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            0
        )
        set.connect(
            tastoetim.id,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            0
        )

        // Apply the updated ConstraintSet back to the ConstraintLayout.
        set.applyTo(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! in fact I was having trouble positioning the button. now it works! But when i add a second button, the first one disappears. what am i doing wrong?  [link](https://codeshare.io/GbMB3O)

Comment: @AndreaDeSimone You are sharing a layout params between the two buttons. Each needs it's own since that is where the layout info is stored. A way to check your layouts is with the Layout Inspector (Tools->Layout Inspector).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set the height equal to the height of the parent.

Let's assume that the parent is a linear layout with id = layVert:

```
tastoetim.layoutParams.height = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layVert).layoutParams.height
```

Comment: Of course, but in my case parent.height is wrap_content so child height needs to change accordingly